# Python curses does not work with command substitution

Tags: python, shell, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I was using python project [pick](https://github.com/wong2/pick) to select an option from a list. Below code returns the option and index.

```
option, index = pick(options, title)
```

Pick uses curses library from python. I want to pass the output of my python script to shell script.

`variable output = $(pythonfile.py)`

but it gets stuck on the curses screen. It cannot draw anything. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Actually `pick` uses ncurses (it relies upon the `use_default_colors` method if you enable `multi_select`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pick` gets stuck because when you use `$(pythonfile.py)`, the shell redirects the output of `pythonfile.py` as if it were a pipe.  Also, the output of `pick` contains characters for updating the screen (not what you want).  You can work around those problems by

- redirecting the output of `pythonfile.py` to `/dev/tty`
- ensuring that your `pythonfile.py` writes **its** result to the standard error, and
- directing the standard error in the shell script to the output of the `$(...)` construct.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=$(python basic.py 2>&1 >/dev/tty )
echo "result '$foo'"
```

and in `pythonfile.py`, doing

```
import sys

print(option, index, file=sys.stderr)
```

rather than

```
print(option, index)
```

Comment: I found a workaround by storing the currrent stdout to a new stream, and then passing this stream to the subprocess. Your way of doing this is better.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the output of a Python script to a Bash variable you need to specify the command with which to open the python file inside the variable's declaration.

Like so:

`variable_output=$(python pythonfile.py)`

**Furthermore**, if you'd like to pass a variable from Python to bash you could use Python's sys module and then redirect the stderr.

Like so:

test.py

```
import sys
test_var = (str(3 + 3))
sys.exit(test_var)
```

test.sh

```
test_var=$(python3 test.py 2>&1)
echo $testvar
```

Now, if we run `test.sh` we get the output `6`.